# Help identifying a low-res kanji

Tags: kanji, writing-identification

I've been playing an older Japanese video game, and I've come across a kanji that I'm unable to identify. I've attempted to use the radical lookup on jisho.org, but the low-resolution is making that difficult as well.

[image: kanji]

Here's the context:

[image: full version]

Comment: 古き言い伝えに曰く(iwaku)　かつて　翼持つ者どもの反乱あり　されど彼ら敗れたり　彼ら栄光を失い　白き翼もがれ　暗き地の底へと堕されたり

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like 「彼」.   A smart thing to do would be to show us the surrounding characters --- in other words, context.

Comment: Good point. I updated my question.

Comment: Good.  It is 「彼」 for sure then.  「彼ら」 means "they".